# How can I run a custom function on a jQuery element?

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-selectors

How can I achieve this?

```
$(".my_selected .element").myCustomFunction();
```

or maybe even simply this?

```
$(".my_selected .element").???????(myCustomFunction());
```

Where the function will know that `$(this)` equals `$(".my_selected .element")`.

Thank you!

Comment: Here's a tutorial on how to do that while I write up an answer: http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/02/building-your-first-jquery-plugin-that.html

Comment: Have a look at: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$.fn.myCustomFunction = function(){
    // this or $(this) is $(".my_selected .element")

}
```

Comment: `this`  is `$('.my_selected .element')`.

Comment: @FelixKling: heh.visited your profile with unicorns plugin -> result[[1](http://i.imgur.com/ASDDL.jpg), [2](http://i.imgur.com/OczA7.png)]

Comment: don't forget the semicolon at the end : )

Comment: No need for `$(this)` as `this` has already been wrapped in a jquery object for you, if i understand the documentation right.

Comment: @Mohammad: it's not necessary

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder: both can be used, I have already specified "this or $(this)"

Comment: Yes, you are right, both can be used. But it is better to use `this` as unnecessarily wrapping the already wrapped object can have a  performance penalty if working with a vast number of elements, just saying.

Comment: @Interstellar_Coder: sure it is. I have just showed it to OP to be more specific

Comment: Hehe, I also wrote such a plugin once and it is interesting how similar both of them are...

Answer (score 3):

Write a plugin: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring

Answer (score 1):

You extend jQuery's functionality by adding your own function as so:

```
jQuery.fn.myCustomFunction = function() {

};
```

The `this` keyword works as intended within the function if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below, see a working **[demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/usmanhalalit/zNC3W/)**

```
(function( $ ){
  $.fn.myCustomFunction= function() {

    alert($(this).html());

  };
})( jQuery );

$(".my_selected .element").myCustomFunction();
```

It is the simple way of extending jQuery

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want the each function if you aren't talking about actually writing a jQuery plugin.  If you know all of your items returned from the selector support the function you could just do something like.

```
$('li').each(function(index) {
    alert(index + ': ' + $(this).text());
});
```

Additional information about this jQuery approach http://api.jquery.com/each/