# How to create custom JQuery function and how to use it?

Tags: jquery, function

I'm searching for information about that - "How to create custom (own) JQuery function and how to use it"

I've searched in Google, but I didn't found information about that.

Can you explain in details, about custom functions?

Comment: What do you mean "custom" jQuery function? Extending the framework?

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring  http://www.queness.com/post/112/a-really-simple-jquery-plugin-tutorial http://www.authenticsociety.com/blog/jQueryPluginTutorial_Beginner  Those were the first 3 links from a Google search.  Do those not work for you?  What specifically is your question?

Comment: is it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7456435/how-can-i-run-a-custom-function-on-a-jquery-element you are looking for?

Comment: define "custom function". It could mean a number of different things...like a "plugin" for example or a custom event handler

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page Click on *"Plugin Authoring"*

Comment: I learned how to write my own jQuery plugins after reading the official documentation and a couple online tutorials I found on Google.  So what happened after you did that?

Answer (score 70):

By "custom function" I am assuming you mean "plugin". If that's the case, there is a good [tutorial on the jQuery site](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring). The basic idea is this:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function() {
        return this.each(function() {
            //Do stuff
        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Basically, the code above does a few things. Firstly, it captures the value of `jQuery` and passes it into an anonymous function where it can then be referred to as `$` (this is so that users of your plugin who happen to be using the `$` identifier for something else can still use it.)

It then declares a method on `$.fn`, which is just an alias for `$.prototype`. Inside that method, `this` refers to the matched set of elements on which the plugin has been called. Since thats a jQuery object, and may contain multiple elements, you need to iterate over that set (that's why the `each` is there).

The `return` statement is used to maintain chainability of the plugin with other jQuery methods. Since `each` returns an instance of jQuery, the plugin itself returns an instance of jQuery, and other jQuery methods can obviously be called on an instance of jQuery.

Comment: Yes, I mean this. Can you explain in details, how to use and syntax of plugin.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Now, when I know for what I'll searching for - there is no problem - Plugin, no custom function. Thanks!

Comment: @Jordan - Can you not read the various links that people have provided to you? There is far more information in those than you are going to get from this answer. However, I have edited in a little explanation of what's going on.

Comment: Very good. Why isn't this the accepted answer?

Answer (score 8):

As gesutery said, use [`extend()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/). You can add your own properties and functions as values:

```
        $(function(){
            $.extend({
                propAsString: '',
                propAsNumber: 12345,
                propAsObject: {},
                propAsFunction: function() {
                    //your function code
                }
            });

        $.propAsFunction();     //call your function
        });
```

Answer (score 7):

you can use it like this

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#button').click(function(){
            $(this).myFunction();
         });
         $.fn.myFunction = function() { 
            alert('test'); 
         }
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

```
(function($){
    $.fn.extend({ 
        //plugin name - animatemenu
        animateMenu: function(options) {

            //Settings list and the default values
            var defaults = {
                animatePadding: 60,
                defaultPadding: 10,
                evenColor: '#ccc',
                oddColor: '#eee'
            };

            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

            return this.each(function() {
                var o =options;

                //Assign current element to variable, in this case is UL element
                var obj = $(this);              

                //Get all LI in the UL
                var items = $("li", obj);

                //Change the color according to odd and even rows
                $("li:even", obj).css('background-color', o.evenColor);             
                $("li:odd", obj).css('background-color', o.oddColor);                     

                //Attach mouseover and mouseout event to the LI  
                items.mouseover(function() {
                    $(this).animate({paddingLeft: o.animatePadding}, 300);

                }).mouseout(function() {
                    $(this).animate({paddingLeft: o.defaultPadding}, 300);
                });

            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 3):

For those who are looking for a "custom function" as per the title, it is as simple as:

```
if(window.$)
    window.$.customMethod = function() { * your code here * };
```

This will then work like `$.ajax()` does

Answer (score 2):

I wanted my custom functions to be invoked like `$.myfunction()`. I defined those functions in an external js file somewhat like this

```
$.myfunction = function(){

//Your code here    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you got the code below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    function getFormData($form){
        var unindexed_array = $form.serializeArray();
        var indexed_array = {};

        $.map(unindexed_array, function(n, i){
            indexed_array[n['name']] = n['value'];
        });

        return indexed_array;
    }

    $("#form_name").submit(function (event) {
        var formData = getFormData($(this));
        console.log(formData);
        
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

And it works just fine. But if you want to turn that function into a jQuery plugin, you can rewrite it as:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $.fn.getFormData = function() {
        var unindexed_array = this.serializeArray();
        var indexed_array = {};

        $.map(unindexed_array, function(n, i){
            indexed_array[n['name']] = n['value'];
        });

        return indexed_array;
    };

    $("#form_name").submit(function (event) {
        var formData = $(this).getFormData();
        console.log(formData);

        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

That's it. You can find more information in the official [JQuery documentation.](https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)