# Add methods to function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add method to a function such that i can call them in a chain

What i want to do:

If you have used jQuery , then you must have seen the syntax like

```
$("#ID");
```

returns element

```
$("#ID").css("property")
```

returns css value of property of element

How can i do it by defining custom methods with same syntax without using jQuery ?

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550866/how-to-create-custom-jquery-function-and-how-to-use-it

Comment: I recommend reading the jQuery source code!

Comment: I did not mean extending jQuery framework or making any sort of plugin .jQuery was used only for better understanding .

Comment: The technical term for this is "method chaining", main idea behind it is to finish all methods with `return this;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simple one:

```
function Get( element_id ) {
    this.node = document.querySelector(element_id);
    this.css = function(prop, val) {};
}

var get = function( element_id )
{
    return new Get( element_id );
};

get('#ID').css("property");
```

Comment: thanks .... just need 8 more minutes to accept your answer .

Comment: What if I wanted to add a method which is not based on a DOM element? One example of what I mean is the famous $.get from jQuery. If I add methods in the way described (which is good and served me well) they are not found if I call them using `get.method(params)`. Instead, I would have to use `get().method(params)` as `get` is a function after all. That approach is not bad, but anyway I would like to know how to achieve a `get.method(params)`

Comment: @jorgefpastor Then you would add the function as a property: `get.method = function(val){...}`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean, but I'll give a try.

Method chaining is something that is usually performed by returning the `this` object from the prototype's methods:

```
function MyClass(...) {
    ...
}

MyClass.prototype = {
    methodOne: function(...) {
        ...
        return this;
    },
    methodTwo: function(...) {
        ...
        return this;
    },
    ...
};
```

So you can do:

```
var obj = new MyClass(...);

obj.methodOne(...).methodTwo(...);
```

This can be useful when you don't actually expect a value in return, or it can't be applied. For example:

```
function MyClass(name) {
    this.name = name;
}
MyClass.prototype.greet = function(greeting) {
    return greeting + " " + this.name;
}

var obj = new MyClass("John");
alert(obj.greet("Hello")); // It alerts "Hello John".
```

In this case you *need* the value from the `greet` method.