# JQuery generic tool to get field attributes.

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a generic javascript tool to get form field name, id and its value with JQuery.

```
<div id="StudentForm">
<div><input id='name' name='name' value='John' /></div>
</div>
```

For example, I want to get all fields inside 'StudentForm' div, output its id, name and its value. how to write a generic toolkit or API ?

I like JQuery, so I prefer JQuery solution.

Answer (score 0):

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Qg9WJ/)

HTML:

```
<div id="StudentForm">
    <div><input id='name' name='name' value='John' /></div>
    <div><input id='name1' name='name1' value='John1' /></div>
    <div><input id='name2' name='name2' value='John2' /></div>
    <div><input id='name3' name='name3' value='John3' /></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
var all = ''; //if you need all at once

$('#StudentForm > div > input').each(
    function(){
        if(all.length == 0){
        all = $(this).val();
        }else{
        all = all + ':' + $(this).val() ;
        }
        alert(   'value : '+$(this).val()+'\n'+
                 'name  : '+$(this).attr('id')+'\n'+
                 "use $(this).attr('any atribute') for any other attr you need"

             );

    })
alert(all)
```

I hope this is what you are looking for ..

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple jQuery plugin

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.getAttributes = function () {
        return [$(this).attr('id'), $(this).attr('name'), $(this).val()];
    }
}(jQuery));
```

And use it like this

```
$('#StudentForm').find('input').each(function () {
    alert($(this).getAttributes());
});
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/aQqDJ/2)

For more information on jQuery plugins, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9550886/1370722)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery offers the [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) and [serializeArray()](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) methods that do most of what you're looking for.