# How to gaunruntee unique custom names for events on iframe object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set jquery events on an iframe object, and then trigger them with the jquery trigger command, and these are for custom events. How can I gauruntee any custom event name I pick won't be the same as any out of the box event names that dom elements already listen to?

Thanks

Comment: You can create a kind of namespace for your events by adding a prefix to your event names.

Comment: You add namespace to them

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason you can't just write a [jQuery plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550866/how-to-create-custom-jquery-function-and-how-to-use-it)?

Comment: @aug what's the relevance? Doesn't matter if you trigger an event from inside a plugin or not ... can still collide if another same named event exists

Answer (score 0):

Just namespace the events.

Following is an example using `click`. Triggering the namespaced version programmatically doesn't trigger the standard one but manually clicking on the original element still triggers both event handlers

```js
// pre-exisiting click event listener
$('#existing-elem').on('click', function(){
   console.log('Existing event handler triggered')
});
// new one you add
$('#existing-elem').on('click.yourNameSpace', function(){
     console.log('yourNameSpace event handler triggered')
});

// listener for demo "Trigger" button
$('#demo-test').click(function(){
   // won't cause original non-namespaced listener to trigger
   $('#existing-elem').trigger('click.yourNameSpace')
 
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="existing-elem">
  Existing element - click me
</button>

<button id="demo-test">
 Trigger namespaced event
</button>
```