# How to create a getter and setter for jquery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a getter and a setter for the `$` object, similar to the `val()` function for a DOM object.

If the `val` is called without parameters, the getter is invoked. With one parameter, the setter is invoked.

I have tried with

```
$.fn.simpleSearch = function() {
    return _variable;
}

$.fn.simpleSearch = function (search) {
    _variable = search;
}
```

But it does not work.

Any hint?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create custom JQuery function and how to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550866/how-to-create-custom-jquery-function-and-how-to-use-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot define `$.fn.simpleSearch` twice. The 2nd definition will override the first.

You can set up a simple getter and setter like this:

```
$.fn.simpleSearch = function (search) {
    if ( typeof search != 'undefined' ) {
        _variable = search;
    }
    return _variable;
}

console.log( $(jQuery).simpleSearch() )
console.log( $(jQuery).simpleSearch('foo') )
```

However, this code is not complete because `_variable` needs to be defined somewhere. Do you intend it to be a global variable? A property of an object?

Also see [How to create custom JQuery function and how to use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550866/how-to-create-custom-jquery-function-and-how-to-use-it)

Comment: Thanks. That link does not solve my question. I know how to create custom jQuery functions. I was only missing the `typeof search != 'undefined'` part.